# Python - Using Input From CSV File/Splitting a String

Tags: python, string, csv, input

I'm very new to Python. I don't have a strong handle on all of the vocabulary.

My current task includes leading data from a CSV file in the format of:

```
row1data1,row1data2,row1data3
row2data1,row2data2,row2data3
etc.
```

From what I've gathered, the csv.reader/csvfile built-in module creates a single string from each row. I need two strings from each row, with the comma being the delimiter.

This is the my current code and output.

CODE:

```
import csv
with open('Sparrow.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    CSVReader = csv.reader(csvfile, quotechar='|')
    for row in CSVReader:
       print( "TEXT" )
       print( "\n" )
       print( "TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'%s'" % " ".join(row))
       print( "\n" )
       print( "TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'%s'" % " ".join(row))
       print( "\n" )
       print( "TEXT" )       
       print( "\n" )
       print( "('%s'));" % " ".join(row))
       print( "\n" )
       print( "\n" )
```

OUTPUT

```
TEXT
TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row1data1 row1data2 row1data3'
TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row1data1 row1data2 row1data3'
TEXT
('row1data1 row1data2 row1data3'));


TEXT
TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row2data1 row2data2 row2data3'
TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row2data1 row2data2 row2data3'
TEXT
('row2data1 row2data2 row2data3'));
```

Again, to clarify, I need to split the strings so the output is as displayed below.

```
TEXT
TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row1data1'
TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row1data2'
TEXT
('row1data3'));


TEXT
TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row2data1'
TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row2data2'
TEXT
('row2data3'));
```

I know this is something very easy that I'm missing and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks like you have whitespace errors in your code.

Comment: I don't receive errors. Some information is edited out of both the code and output, but it shouldn't effect it syntactically.

Comment: in python whitespace is significant. in your example your print statements are on the same level as the loop they are supposed to be inside of.

Comment: had to change to `for i in range(1,2,3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it:

```
print( "TEXT" )
print( "\n" )
for i in range(1):
    print "TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'%s'" % row[i]
print( "\n" )
print( "('%s'));" % row[2]
```

Comment: No, I didn't realize you defined the item in the previous line. My mistake.

Comment: Actually, it repeats each of those defined lines 3 times with each data type. I need a single line per data input.

Comment: can you paste your output?

Comment: I'm trying to get the inline code format to work here, one minute.

Comment: `TEXT
TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row1data1'
TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row1data2'
TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row1data3'
TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row1data1'
TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row1data2'
TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row1data3'
TEXT
('row1data1'));
('row1data2'));
('row1data3'));`

Comment: `TEXT


TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row1data2'


TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'row1data1'


TEXT


('row1data3'));
`

Comment: That's it. In the exact order I needed it. Thank you!

Comment: had to change to `for i in range(1,2,3)`

Comment: Cool, dont forget to select an answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Split the line before printing it

```py
for row in CSVReader:
    a,b,c = row.split(',')
    print( "TEXT\n" )
    print( "TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'%s'\n" % " ".join(a))
    print( "TEXT INPUT REQUIRED:'%s'\n" % " ".join(b))
    print( "TEXT\n" )       
    print( "('%s'));\n\n" % " ".join(c))
```

Comment: Received output:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'